# Как запустить MySQL через командную строку?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите как запустить MySQL через командную строку? Установлен OpenServer. Я так понимаю, что нужно какой-то путь прописать в командной строке или команду.

Answer (score 2):

В контекстном меню OpenServer "дополнительно" -> "консоль"

```
mysql -u root
```

либо если нет такого, то найди где у тебя mysql.exe, добавь путь к нему в environment в системную PATH. запускаешь обычную cmd и ту же команду пишешь.

Comment: 1) mysql -ulogin -ppassword или 2) mysql -ulogin -p а потом вписывать пароль. 3)Руководство пользователя https://ospanel.io/docs/